# Is there an minimum android version to use android-ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with android ConstraintLayout feature...
In my app I use a ConstraintLayout, everything works fine when I install my app on a 9+ android version, but when I install the app on a lower android version the app is crashing.
In my android project I have:
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 26
compileSdkVersion 28

Anyone have any idea what might causing it? Or a way to fix it?

**Edit:**
Thanks to **@Nikos Hidalgo**!
I didn't understand the error message correctly. it was my gradient background that broke everything..

The error I get is as follows:

```
11-12 15:44:32.580 11651-11651/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.repondeurtexto, PID: 11651
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.repondeurtexto/com.example.repondeurtexto.FirstActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.repondeurtexto.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.repondeurtexto.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.repondeurtexto:drawable/gradient" (7f07006c)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07006c a=-1 r=0x7f07006c}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4017)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3779)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4001)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:509)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:505)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:575)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.repondeurtexto.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

In my `build.gradle` I set this:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: this is the line in your logcat you should be paying attention to: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.repondeurtexto:drawable/gradient" (7f07006c)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07006c a=-1 r=0x7f07006c}

API21 can support constraint layout just fine.

Comment: Could you post your xml please?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095063/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable-color-or-path

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) states, ConstraintLayout for now is only available as a support library that you can use on Android systems starting with API level 9 (Gingerbread).

Answer (score 0):

Your targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion should be same.

```
targetSdkVersion 28
compileSdkVersion 28
```

Comment: not sure if that's where the issue lies. Target SDK doesn't have to be the same as Compile SDK.

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintLayout is available in an API library that's compatible with Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher. This page provides a guide to building a layout with ConstraintLayout in Android Studio 2.3 or higher.

[Build responsive UI with ContraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project)

Ensure you have the required modules in your gradle.Also see this link to solve [NullPointExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Check if you have ids that are conflicting with the new design library.

Check your XML file name,make sure your XML file name is included in your MainActivity layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.xmlfilename_main);
```