# Error in fetching image from Drawable in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm using android studio and getting error when i'm any image from Drawable and when fetching from mipmap it is working correctly. I store image in drawable and another image in mipmap but don't know every time image which source is Drawable send error.[image: This 2nd part of image]

[image: This type of error occur]

Comment: With the information you provide, we can't really figure out what is your problem. Please create an SSCCE or append the affected part of your code to your question.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text. That said, have a look at this post, and let us know if that's your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29095063.

Comment: Duplicate of [Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095063/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable-color-or-path)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i solved it. Its actually targeted device problem. imageView is not sported in less sdk device.  I'm trying it with 19 SDk and it showing me error . but now i attach another mobile with 26 sdk and its work.