# Crashes & ANRs Not understood

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

[This is The Crash Which I am not understood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7afkw.png)

i tried to run my app from android studio & it didn't give me any errors or bugs but when i installed my app from play store it gives me this crash and this is the log in android studio of installed app

```
Process: com.genius.spiritualnote, PID: 18916
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.genius.spiritualnote/com.example.updatedspiritualnote.ui.HomeActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.genius.spiritualnote:dimen/hint_pressed_alpha_material_dark with resource ID #0x7f070093
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3743)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3911)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2330)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8245)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.genius.spiritualnote:dimen/hint_pressed_alpha_material_dark with resource ID #0x7f070093
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.genius.spiritualnote:dimen/hint_pressed_alpha_material_dark" (7f070093) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x4/d=0x3f333333 a=16 r=0x7f070093}
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:905)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:744)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1002)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:992)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:931)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:693)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:455)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:90)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:98)
    at com.example.updatedspiritualnote.ui.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:234)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8151)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3712)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3911)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2330)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8245)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
```

Comment: Can you attach Android-Studio Logcat while launching the app (installed from play store) and check if more info for the crash appears on the logs there?

Comment: here is the android studio log

Comment: Not so cryptic anymore ;) `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.genius.spiritualnote:dimen/hint_pressed_alpha_material_dark" (7f070093) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x4/d=0x3f333333 a=16 r=0x7f070093}`

Comment: You can check this Q&A here maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095063/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable-color-or-path

Comment: how can i know this resource?

Comment: dimen/hint_pressed_alpha_material_dark is missing, completely or for given configuration.