Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable org.radarcns.detail:drawable/status_searching with resource ID #0x7f080130
I am getting the exception:
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable org.radarcns.detail:drawable/status_searching with resource ID #0x7f080130


Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "org.radarcns.detail:drawable/status_searching" (7f080130) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f080130 a=11 r=0x7f080130}
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:828)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:673)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1002)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:992)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:931)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:810)
       at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:1049)
       at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:485)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:149)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:137)
       at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:66)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:91)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:102)
       at org.radarcns.detail.SourceRowView$updateSourceStatus$1.invoke(SourceRowView.kt:155)
       at org.radarcns.detail.SourceRowView$updateSourceStatus$1.invoke(SourceRowView.kt:152)
       at org.radarbase.android.util.ChangeApplier.applyIfChanged(ChangeApplier.kt:72)
       at org.radarcns.detail.SourceRowView.updateSourceStatus(SourceRowView.kt:152)
       at org.radarcns.detail.SourceRowView.display(SourceRowView.kt:148)
       at org.radarcns.detail.MainActivityViewImpl.update$lambda$6(MainActivityViewImpl.kt:157)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)


The code in SourceRowView where I am getting this error is as follows:
    private val mStatusIcon: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.status_icon)
    mStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.status_searching)

Where R.drawable.status_searching is present in src/main/res/drawable which contains:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_searching" />
</layer-list>

Now @drawable/ic_searching.png is in png format present in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi.
Even all the resources are present it is giving ResourceNotFound, I am not understanding why it is happening?

The problem you have here is in the logcat:

NotFoundException: Resource "org.radarcns.detail:drawable/status_searching" is not a Drawable (color or path)

As your app can't find that image in the drawable folder. This can be in case you have the image in @drawable-hdpi, @drawable-mdpi folders but your app running with @drawable-xhdpi screen density.
To be sure you have fallback @drawable/ic_searching.png file for missing density, you need to have file in @drawable too.
You can find similar issue explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34707995/4977439

I recommend to use the below function.
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.your_image));


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
